# Find latest dowloaded item and download time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a CRM system and a web download service. At the web download the customers identify with customer name. In the crm system I have `crmID` as identifier. To map web customer name to a `crmID`, I have a mapping table. As some customers tend to write their customer names differently each time, many web names may link to the same `crmID`. The linking system is always in sync, and no problem.

```
crmMap( webName VACHAR(100),  
        crmID CHAR(6) )  
webDownload( webName VARCHAR(100), 
             item VARCHAR(100), 
             itemVersion VARCHAR(100), 
             downloadTime DATETIME )
```

What I want is to display what each customer (`crmMap.crmID`) downloaded last time `(webDownload.item  and webDownload.itemVersion)` and when that happened `(webDownload.downloadTime)`.

Comment: The real challenge is to get only the entry with the latest downloadTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to determine this:

```
select m.crnId, d.item, d.itemVersion, d.downloadTime
from crmMap m
inner join
(
  select webname, item, itemVersion, downloadTime,
    row_number() over(partition by webname order by downloadTime desc) rn
  from webDownload
) d
  on m.webName = d.webName
where rn = 1
```

or even a subquery:

```
select m.crnId, d.item, d.itemVersion, d.maxTime
from crmMap m
inner join 
(
  select max(downloadTime) maxTime, webName, item, itemVersion
  from webDownload
  group by webName, item, itemVersion
) d
  on m.webName = d.webName
```

Edit, if you only want the `MAX()` download time, then you will want to use:

```
select m.crnId, m.item, m.itemVersion, m.maxTime
from crmMap m
inner join 
(
  select max(downloadTime) maxTime
  from webDownload
) d
  on m.downloadTime = d.webName
```

Comment: @BluehighMountain can you post some sample data? or create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: The solution actually does not seem to give me what I want: See above. It gives me the latest download time for each combination of crmID, item, itemVersion. I need the latest overall download time per crmID, and what item and itemVersion that was downloaded by the crmID at that time

Comment: @BluehighMountain It would be much easier if you can post some sample data and the expected result.